# In R: How do I test for membership of matrix elements in a list or a vector

Tags: r

Say I have a matrix m

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    3    5    9   11   15   17   21    27
 [2,]    0    0    2    4    8   10   14   16   20    26
 [3,]    0    0    0    2    6    8   12   14   18    24
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    4    6   10   12   16    22
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    6    8   12    18
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    4    6   10    16
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    6    12
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    4    10
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     6
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

dput is:

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 9, 8, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 10, 8, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 15, 14, 12, 10, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 14, 12, 8, 6, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 21, 20, 18, 16, 12, 10, 6, 4, 0, 0, 27, 26, 24, 22, 
18, 16, 12, 10, 6, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 10L))
```

Say I have vector p

```
 [1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71
```

dput is:

```
c(2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 17L, 19L, 23L, 29L)
```

I want to set all the values in the matrix that are not in p to zero

How do I elegantly do that?

Comment: How do you do it not elegantly?

Comment: @akrun, that, sorry didn't know about dput

Comment: No problem.  I posted the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
m1[!m1 %in% p] <- 0
```

Or as in your previous question, we can multiply the logical index with 'm1' so that 'TRUE/FALSE`gets coerced to binary (`1/0`) and multiplying '0/FALSE' values with corresponding elements of 'm1' gives '0' as outcome.

```
m1 <- (m1 %in% p)*m1
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
15L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 16L, 14L, 12L, 
8L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 20L, 18L, 16L, 12L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 27L, 26L, 24L, 22L, 18L, 16L, 12L, 10L, 6L, 0L), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L))

p <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47,
          53, 59, 61, 67, 71)
```

Comment: R is beautiful I have to say